# Find the point of intersection of the tangents to the curve $y=(x-2)^2-1$ at its points of intersection with the line $x-y=3$

Tags: conic-sections

$$x=y+3$$
Then 
$$y=(y+3-2)^2-1$$
$$y=0,-1$$

So $$x=3,2$$

Then points of intersection of line with parabola are $(3,0)$ and $(2,-1)$

Now $$y=(x-2)^2-1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2(x-2)(-2)=-4(x-2)$$

The slopes of tangents will be $-4, 0$

Then tangents will be 
$$y-0=-4(x-3)$$
And $$y+1=0$$
$$y=-1$$

Therefore 
$$-1=-4(x-3)$$
$$\frac 14 =x-3$$
$$x=\frac{13}{4}$$

So the POI will be $(\frac{13}{4}, -1)$

But then answer is $(\frac 52, -1)$

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2(x-2)$$

Comment: Okay, that’s embarrassing

Comment: Your error in computing the derivative aside, do you know about pole-polar relationships? The point you’re supposed to find is the pole of the given line.

Comment: @amd I am not aware of it (yet)